# Jackson @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonIdentityReference and custom serialization

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

I'm using jackson to serialize my objects in JSON. This objects are JPA Entities, so with circular associations.

So, I have this simple POJO:

```java
private static class Bean {
 
    String id;
    String description;
    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = Bean.class)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = false)
    Bean ref;
}
```

And I serialize this instances:

```java
Bean a = new Bean();
a.id = "1";
a.description = "The first";

Bean b = new Bean();
b.id = "2";
b.description = "The second";

Bean c = new Bean();
c.id = "3";
b.description = "The last one";

// setup refs
a.ref = b;
b.ref = c;
c.ref = a; // circular
```

I need this JSON at the end:

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "description" : "The first",
    "ref": {
        "id" : "2",
        "description" : "The second",
        "ref": {
            "id" : "3",
            "description" : "The last one"
            "ref" : {
                "id" : "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need that the circular reference serialize only the "id" property (and omit the others) and the "ref" **must continue to be a object**.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set ref as an object without another ref.

```
c.ref = new Bean();
c.ref.id = a.id;
```

Comment: The serialization must to guarantee this, not the developer. This was only a example, my real scenario has a more complex (like JPA entities with associations) serialization.